# xlsstream on PHP 4.32 weird output

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls

I've been trying to export the same data on the sample excel that's included with this library:

[Link to Library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1919-PHP-Stream-wrapper-to-read-and-write-MS-Excel-files.html)

and i've been getting some weird outputs like this one:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99O4D.png)

Why, oh Why....here's my code:

```
<?php
include_once("header.auth.php");
    require_once "xlsstream/excel.php";
    $fecha_de_corrido=date("YmdHi");
    $export_file = "xlsfile://tmp/InformeCertificados_".$fecha_de_corrido.".xls"; 

$fp = fopen($export_file, "wb"); 
if (!is_resource($fp))
{ 
    die("Cannot open $export_file");
}

$assoc = array(
    array("Sales Person" => "Sam Jackson", "Q1" => "$3255", "Q2" => "$3167", "Q3" => 3245, "Q4" => 3943),
    array("Sales Person" => "Jim Brown", "Q1" => "$2580", "Q2" => "$2677", "Q3" => 3225, "Q4" => 3410),
    array("Sales Person" => "John Hancock", "Q1" => "$9367", "Q2" => "$9875", "Q3" => 9544, "Q4" => 10255),
);

fwrite($fp,serialize($assoc));

fclose($fp);


header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($export_file) . "\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data" );
        readfile($export_file);
        exit;
        ?>
```

Plz any help would be great.

Comment: `application/x-msexcel` is an invalid mime type, should be `application/vnd.ms-excel`... that probably doesn't help

Comment: I tried that and didn't work either...

Comment: I can't answer why, I have no idea about the inner workings of your xlsstream/excel.php; but please not that it isn't `PHPExcel`, which you have tagged against your question

Comment: yes i know, but i was hoping the ones that know about xlsx exporting though php could help me, the library (excel.php) is on the first link so maybe you can take a look :D